# puppeteerExtra not correctly bundled with webpack

Tags: webpack, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer extra with webpack and typescript.
When I run webpack with `npm run build` I get an error saying:  `Property 'launch' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/pathtoproject/node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index")`.

Code:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import stealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
import chromium from "@sparticuz/chromium";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ // this is where the error happens
  headless:"true",
  executablePath:"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
});
```

What do you think is causing the error?

This is my `webpack.config.mjs`:

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import NodePolyfillPlugin from 'node-polyfill-webpack-plugin';
import nodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

export default {
    entry:"./src/index.ts",
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.ts$/,
                use:"ts-loader",
                include:[path.resolve(__dirname,"src")],
                // sideEffects:true
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensionAlias: {
            '.js': ['.js', '.ts'],
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename:"index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        iife: false
    },
    optimization: {
        usedExports: false, // <- no remove unused function
    },
    plugins:[new NodePolyfillPlugin()],
    target: 'node',
};
```

This is my ts.config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        
    "experimentalDecorators": true,              
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "coverage"]
}
```

And package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.10.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "^119.0.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.130",
    "@types/serverless": "^3.12.19",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
    "puppeteer-core": "^21.5.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
    "serverless": "^3.38.0",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "sideEffects": [
    "./src/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: To transpile it and pack it for lambda.